# Insert a row below the last cell and not above it

Tags: excel, vba, insert, row

Can anyone please help me with this?

I am trying to write a macro that will insert a new row with text, after the last row that has text in it on page 1 - please see the image below.

[image]

I want the macro to insert a new row on **PAGE 1**, after row 16, thus expanding the border of page 1 or in other words **below it**.

But it only inserts a row above for some reason. I need it to insert below.

Here is the code -

```
Sub Macro5()


lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Rows(lastrow).Select

Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove


End Sub
```

Should be a simple task, but for some reason, I can't find the answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've found the last row, but where is the text you're trying to add? All it looks like you're doing is inserting a blank row. It's inserting it above because you have the last row selected. You wouldn't insert a blank row below as that's pointless. Sounds like you want to expand the print area.

Comment: Yes i want to expand the print area and insert a row after the last one with some random text for now, for example insert the word - 'ok'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify just one line

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

### Insert Row

- This will insert the row above, and then will copy the row below to the row above keeping its formatting.
- Not sure if this will keep the last row on `Page 1` though.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro5()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Rows(LastRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
    Rows(LastRow + 1).Copy Rows(LastRow)
End Sub
```